# How to implement iterable consuming multiprocess pool in Python 3

Tags: python, networking, queue, python-multiprocessing, pool

I need to use a worker pool of processes in order to make parallel network complex stuff. So, every worker must be initialized with its own session object (that will be instanciated once and for all in the init phase) thus it can login in trasparent way to the others. The main process must read a file, and put all the tasks I need into a Queue object.

The Queue is shared among the Pool. Every process return a list object to the parent once the Queue is empty and all the work has been done.

The first step was to find a baseline. I started with the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
 
def init:
    session = login()
    # every process performs a login and uses the session object to do the work in f


def f(q):
    result = list()
    # do network stuff with the session object
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open("task_list","w")
    tasks = f.readlines()
    q = Queue()
    for EachTask in tasks:
        q.put(EachTask)
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,), init=init)
    p.start()
    q.join()
    # wait all tasks to finish, then combine all list objects and write them to file
```

So, how should I edit this code in order to do what I need ? Thank you

Comment: Look into https://github.com/omnilib/aiomultiprocess